# If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{z}=\frac{2}{3}$, then what is the value of the expression $\frac{2a-6c-3e}{2b-6d-3z}$, while $bdz(2b-6c-3z)\ne0$

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, problem-solving

If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{z}=\frac{2}{3}$, then what is the value of the expression $\frac{2a-6c-3e}{2b-6d-3z}$, while $bdz(2b-6c-3z)\ne0$

I attempted to solve the question as follows:

$\frac{2a-6c-3e}{2b-6d-3z}=\frac{2a-6c-2z}{3a-6d-3z}=\frac{2(a-2c-z)-2c}{3(a-2d-z)}$

This is as far as I got. My intuition tells me that the expression is equal to $\frac{2}{3}$ (something which I get after trying a few different values of $a,b,c,d,e,z$), but I don't know how to prove it. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: You are mixing up your numerators and denominators.  You wrote $c$ in numerator and denominator when surely you mean to have a $d$ in the denominator instead.  If you were to trust and assume that there is in fact a single answer rather than several (*which may well be an incorrect assumption*), for example in a contest setting, then you can just choose values of $a,b,\dots$ to make the equalities hold and evaluate.  For instance, letting $a=c=e=2$ and $b=d=z=3$ in which case you have $\dfrac{2a-6c-3e}{2b-6d-3z}=\dfrac{-7\cdot 2}{-7\cdot 3}=\dfrac{2}{3}$

Comment: @JMoravitz, I didn't mean to write d in the denomitaor, the expression is just like I wrote it: $\frac{2a-6c-3e}{2b-6c-3z}$

Comment: In your attempt to solve the question, you made the denominator $3a-6c-3z$. Can you recheck? Also, the numerator is $ -2z$ instead of $-3e$.

Comment: "*I didn't mean to write $d$ in the denominator*"  That has to be a typo... I refuse to believe otherwise.  It should be clear that the final result changes depending on what $c$ is if it weren't a typo.

Comment: @CalvinLin I just skipped a step there, one second I'll make it more clear

Comment: @CalvinLin I've edited it, is it clearer now?

Comment: @JMoravitz This is what the question writes, I don't know if the examiners meant to write something else but wrote this

Comment: Ah, I now see what you're doing. What I thought were typos were just substitutions.

Comment: @CalvinLin $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{2}{3}$, hence $b=\frac{3a}{2}$

Comment: Also, can someone please explain why they downvoted the question? I'm trying to explain what's happening constantly. If there is something you don't understand, please ask me

Comment: Given what you have, I agree with JMor that "If there is no typo, then the final result depends on the value of c". As an example, you can set $ a = e = 2, b=z=3$

Comment: @ManjoyDas that's what the question writes

Comment: If you all believe that that is wrong, do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: That, or acknowledge that the value changes based on the value of $c$.  For instance, setting $a=e=2,~b=z=3,~c=0.00000000002,~d=0.00000000003$ gives one value close to $\frac{2}{3}$ while setting $a=e=2,~b=z=3,~c=20000000000,~d=30000000000$ gives an entirely different value close to $1$.  I encourage you to try the problem where the typo is corrected, properly having a $d$ in the denominator rather than a $c$ and you will find that it does evaluate identically to $\frac{2}{3}$ every time.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I'll send an enquiry to the examiners themselves, and edit the question as soon as they respond, as I see your point

Comment: @JMoravitz you were right, they just responded to me. Thanks for picking up the typo, it's the first time anyone has seen it

Comment: The condition is also then $bdz(2b-6d-3z)\neq 0$, this was to ensure that we aren't in a $\dfrac{0}{0}$ situation in any case, either when talking about $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{2}{3}$ or similar or when talking about $\dfrac{2a-6c-3e}{2b-6d-3z}$.  The condition was just shorthand for $b\neq 0$ and $d\neq 0$ and $z\neq 0$ and $(2b-6d-3z)\neq 0$, writing them all at once rather than separately.  Now that the typo is sorted out, your approach of replacing $b$ with $\dfrac{3}{2}a$ and similar should work just fine.  You should have the ability then to write up the answer below yourself.

Comment: @JMoravitz I just worked it out, by substituting $c=\frac{2d}{3}$, then the expression $=\frac{2a-4d-2z}{3a-6d-3z}=\frac{2}{3}$. Thank you so much for your time and effort, it is much appreciated. Have a great day

Comment: @MichaelBlane Given the high number of problems that you've posted to this site, and how you're "sending an enquiry to the examiners", are these problems "live" for some online contest/assessment/evaluation?

Comment: @CalvinLin no they're not, it's just that I have the contact details of the examiners

Comment: @CalvinLin and also  since most of these questions are pretty old, their solutions don't exist anywhere for me to study the ones I get stuck on

Comment: And I try not to contact the examiners to frequently, so that they don't get sick of me :)

Comment: Also, as you've noticed, I post up questions very frequently, as I go through a lot of practice problems every day and I try to solve as many of them as possible on my own or with research. But often there are questions which I can't solve, those are the questions which I upload to this site

Comment: @MichaelBlane Thanks for explaining! Please continue including your thoughts/working on the problem, which makes it easier to guide you.

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you for your time and effort. This community is truly fabulous. Have a great day